# Teradata - Timestamp conversion

Tags: teradata

I am having a timestamp in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS` and I want to convert it in the format `MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS`.

What is the easiest way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

The format of a timestamp is only applied when it's casted from/to a string

```
-- using Teradata's format
Cast(Cast(ts AS Format 'MM/DD/YYYYBHH:MI:SS') AS VARCHAR(19))

-- shorter using Oracle's To_Char 
To_Char(ts, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```